# Find and edit row in DataTable speed optimization WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datatable, datagrid

I am building a WPF MVVM application. I have a `DataTable`, binded to a `DataGrid`.

The columns of the data table in the beginning are 2 - Name and Value 1.

Name | Value 1

The data table is binded to an `ObservableCollection`, called `mapData`, which holds over 10k records.

When a user selects a `ComboBox` I add dynamically a column, called Value 2.

Name | Value 1 | Value 2

These values both refer to the same name, so when I am adding the column, I use this approach:

```
foreach (var item in mapData)
{
      DataRow row = MapDataTable.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<string>("Name") == item.Name).First();

      if (row != null) //it should be always true, but just in case
      {
           row[2] = item.Value;
      }
}
```

This works as expected, but it takes approximately 6.8s, which is too long.

Can I optimize it somehow?

I tried another approach - instead of iterating through the items of the `ObservableCollection`, I iterate through the rows of the `DataTable`.

```
foreach (DataRow row in MapDataTable.Rows)
{
     if (mapData.Any(x => x.Name == row.Field<string>("Name"))) //should always be true
     {
          var item = mapData.Where(x => x.Name == row.Field<string>("Name")).First();
          row[2] = item.Value;
     }
}
```

This takes approximately 7.1s, which is even longer.

Is there another way to do that?

Comment: Doing it with a for loop instead of using Linq will increase performance. Here is a very good example where you can compare performances. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/178218/for-vs-foreach-vs-linq

Comment: @saklanmaz a `for` loop inside a `foreach` ?

Comment: You can use for loop instead of foreach. Of course you will need to change your code. In addition, an alternative code in the part where you use Linq can speed up your operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to speed this up

```cs
var dict = MapDataTable.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().ToDictionary(x => x.Field<string>("Name"));
foreach (var item in mapData)
{
      if (dict.TryGetValue(item.Name, out var row))
      {
           row[2] = item.Value;
      }
}
```

You can also do this in the opposite direction

```cs
var dict = mapData.ToDictionary(x => x.Name);
foreach (DataRow row in MapDataTable.Rows)
{
     if (dict.TryGetValue(row.Field<string>("Name"), out var item))
     {
          row[2] = item.Value;
     }
}
```

If there are multiple possible matches by `Name` then you need to switch to `ToLookup` or `HashSet`

Comment: Apparently, there is no such thing as MapDataTable.ToDictionary(), but the second one worked like a charm, thank you!

Comment: Sorry that one should work now also

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this in following way & it gives you more freedom and roam to change controls

```
<ItemsControl 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SourceList}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <WrapPanel />
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border>
                    <ScrollViewer>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.Template>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<Button Content="{Binding Value}">
                </Button>
</StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```